# Convert data from MongoDB into native MATLAB format via java driver

Tags: java, matlab, mongodb

I'm trying to import all documents inside a collection into MATLAB via the java driver, but there's something i seem to be missing. I have searched extensively on the net, but couldn't come up with a working solution.

My data inside the mongodb documents is mixed, it consists of numbers as well as strings, so it would be advantageous to convert each document into a struct in MATLAB. I could possibly run a loop for each field of each document and parse the data like that, but i assume that this solution might have a rather heavy performance footprint.

This is my code so far:

```
import com.mongodb.*;

events = mongoConn.getCollection('events');
cursor = events.find();
list = cursor.toArray();
```

At this point, `list` is a java.util.ArrayList and this is where i get stuck. Is there a way to mold this into a struct? All the info i can find on the net talks about arrays of one single data type. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The solution with looping over a cursor with all documents has turned out reasonably well. I will post it here for reference if anybody runs into the same trouble. However, i consider it a rather ugly hack and i strongly suspect it will scale poorly if applied to large datasets, so use this with care. If anybody has a more elegant solution, i'd still be interested to see it (the accepted answer is still up for grabs ). ;-)

```
% // get handle to event collection
events = mongoConn.getCollection('events');

% // get cursor with all event documents
cursor = events.find();

% // parse events
n = 1;
while cursor.hasNext()
    event(n).bolus_id   = cursor.next().get('bolus_id');
    event(n).timestamp  = cursor.curr().get('timestamp');
    event(n).typ        = cursor.curr().get('type');
    event(n).title      = cursor.curr().get('title');
    event(n).value      = cursor.curr().get('value');
    event(n).sta        = cursor.curr().get('start');
    event(n).end        = cursor.curr().get('end');
    n = n + 1;
end

cursor.close();
```